# Fixing column alignment

Tags: html, css

I want column 1 (comment 1) and column 2 (comment 2) to be next to each other and to be floated to the left side. Column 3 (comment 3) should be floated to the right side.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8xzn8xz/)

I've tried a lot but can't make it work with %.

HTML:

```
<div class="comment_one">
    <div class="reitings">
        <div class="rate pluss"><img class="plus" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAIAQMAAAD3KoyyAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAtJREFUeNpjYMAOAAAYAAFG27MLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"> 83</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="comment_two">
    <div class="reitings">
        <div class="rate minuss"><img class="minus" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAIAQMAAAD3KoyyAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAtJREFUeNpjYMAOAAAYAAFG27MLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"> 9</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="comment_three">
    <div class="reitings">
        <div class="rate minuss"><img class="minus" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAIAQMAAAD3KoyyAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAtJREFUeNpjYMAOAAAYAAFG27MLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">Report</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.comment_one {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}
.comment_two {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}
.comment_three {
    float:right;
    width:40%;
}
.reitings {
    display:table;
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid #e9e9e9;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.rate {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:1.5em;
    padding:10%;
}
.rate img {
    vertical-align:middle
}
.pluss {
    background:#f5f5f5;
    color:#4d761a
}
.minuss {
    background:#f5f5f5;
    color:#a8404b;
    border-left:1px solid #e9e9e9;
    text-align:center
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Edited first post.

Comment: Try removing the widths from the floats and the button will align as you want....although it's not clear how this is supposed to look.

Answer (score 0):

**Structure** the HTML:

```
<div id="comments">
    <div class="c1 rate-plus"></div>
    <div class="c2 rate-plus"></div>
    <div class="c3 rate-minus"></div>
</div>
```

Access all divs in `#comments` with `#comments div`. Think about what the divs have in common. Write it in the CSS. For Example:

```
#comments div {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border-left: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Float `c1` and `c2` with **left** and `c3` with **right**.

Complete **CSS**

```
#comments div {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border-left: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.rate-plus {
    color: #4d761a
}

.rate-minus {
    color: #a8404b;
}

.c1, .c2 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.c3 {
    width: 37%;
    float: right;
}
```

Complete **HTML**

```
<div id="comments">
    <div class="c1 rate-plus">
        <img class="plus" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAIAQMAAAD3KoyyAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAtJREFUeNpjYMAOAAAYAAFG27MLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">83
    </div>
    <div class="c2 rate-minus">
        <img class="minus" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAIAQMAAAD3KoyyAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAtJREFUeNpjYMAOAAAYAAFG27MLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">9
    </div>
    <div class="c3 rate-minus">
        <img class="minus" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAIAQMAAAD3KoyyAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAtJREFUeNpjYMAOAAAYAAFG27MLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">Report
    </div>
</div>
```

I've modified it a little bit.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/atum5tco/2/embedded/result/)